# Amazon RDS change collate for mysql database in production without downtime

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I saw a solution like this below:

1. create a new table like your source table.
2. alter that new table the way you want.
3. insert your data into the new table.
4. create indexes etc. as needed on the new table.
5. rename your old table to something like ..._old or whatever.
6. rename your new table to the former name of the old one.
7. copy any missing rows from the _old table to the new one.

[Reference for an above solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6131/mysql-speed-up-execution-of-alter-table)

But the above solution might cause data unavailability if there is a huge amount of data added before copying any missing rows from the _old table to the new one.

Is there any better solution than this, using AWS DMS, etc?

I also want to change the collate of all tables present in the database.
Is it possible to get all the data replicated between two RDS DBs continuously, like new data entered in database A gets into Database B and viceversa?

Comment: You could skip steps 5, 6, and 7 if you just update your app code to use the new table name.

Comment: @jordanm this might result in the unavailability of some data until it's copied to the new database right? I updated the question as well as provided additional details look at it once.